# Android multiple input filters

Tags: android, input, filter

I would like to know how can I set more than one filter on input box?

This is what I'm trying:

```
input.setFilters( new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(20)});
input.setFilters( new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
```

but, only last filter is applied...
I can't find anything on google.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try the following:-

`input.setFilters( new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(20), new InputFilter.AllCaps()});`

or

```
InputFilter[] filters = {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(20), new InputFilter.AllCaps()};
input.setFilters(filters);
```